# Weird black line on top of list view

Tags: android, listview

I am creating a layout with a `ListView` and at the very top of the list there is this weird black line that I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of!  It's part of the `ListView` because it moves up and down as I size the `ListView`.  Has anyone ran into this before?

[image]

I couldn't get DDMS to take a screen capture for some reason so I took a picture of the screen with my G1, so please forgive the quality!  As you can see the line is there at the top of the fade out in the list.
[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3618586/2010-05-07%2014.25.50.jpg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3618586/2010-05-07%2014.25.50.jpg)

Comment: Does it happen on a real device, or even emulator, or just in Eclipse? I imagine posting your layout would help too, if not.

Comment: It happens in both, I'm at home now, but I'll post a screen shot from the device and the layout tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the divider.

I was also looking for a solution to this and I found one :

You can do your own theme with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And setting the theme to your manifest xml file and it works.

The windowContentOverlay to null fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you specify attribute dividerHeight in ListView

`<ListView 
     android:dividerHeight="0.0px"
     android:id="@+id/listview"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>`

in layout xml it is not working for Android 2.2 for some reason
Google groups say that it will be fixed in next cupcake

function `ListView.setDividerHeight(0)` works fine

Answer (score 0):

It is probably coming from the divider of ListView. Check out and play with setting

```
setDividerHeight(0)
```

as well as check header/footer dividers are off or use

```
setFooterDividersEnabled(false)
```

You can also set these in xml of course. e.g.

```
android:dividerHeight="0"
```