# Unexpected visual element in a simple Tab layout

Tags: android, layout, android-tabhost

The screen shot below is of a simplified version of the application from the [Tab Layout tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout#CommonLayouts). You can see a black horizontal line below the tabs. Why is it there and how can I remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `android:padding` attribute from the `FrameLayout`. If you want padding around everything but the top then you'll have to use the `padding/Left/Right/Bottom` attributes.

Comment: This worked great, thanks! I guess the role of the black line is to serve as a drop shadow for the tabs panel.

Answer (score 1):

I think that line results from how the tabs are implemented.  If you look at [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784387/android-weird-black-line-on-top-of-list-view) about a strange black line I found that it was an artifact of the `ActivityGroup` that I was using.  This is the same widget that tabs use.